# Resolving ts(2339) for react-native hooks for useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm using useState in my react-native app as such:

```
const [loginDetails, setLoginDetals] = useState({});
```

When I try to access a property of `loginDetails`, I get a ts(2339) error from eslint:

[image]

I don't really have any interfaces or classes set up for this, but it does get populated with those fields. They are just not explicitly defined.

My eslint and prettier configs are as follows:

eslint

```
{
      

"extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "no-console": "off",
    "func-names": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": [
        "airbnb",
        "prettier",
        "airbnb-typescript",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
      ],
      "plugins": ["prettier", "@typescript-eslint"],
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    }
  ]
}
```

prettier

```
{
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "printWidth": 200,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "endOfLine": "auto",
    "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

This error does not cause any compile or runtime issues, but I'd still like to fix it.

What's the proper way to handle it?

Comment: `const [loginDetails, setLoginDetals] = useState({email: '', password: ''});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can fix this, set a default value for username and password in the state.

```
const [loginDetails, setLoginDetals] = useState({email: '', password: ''});
```

If these are optional fields, then use an interface like below,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface Login {
  username?: string;
  password?: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const [loginDetails, setLoginDetals] = useState<Login>({});
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{loginDetails.username}</h1>
      <h2>{loginDetails.password}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/old-fire-upgvi?file=/src/App.tsx:0-355